# Issues with dualbooting after installing windows 8 (boot-repair not working!)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I used to dual boot ubuntu and windows 7 before I decided to format my windows partition and install windows 8 instead. As always, my grub went missing (only windows loading) and I run boot-repair-disk from usb. However, the recommended repair fails with the message:

> You have installed on sda5 a Linux version which is not EFI-compatible. It is probably incompatible with your computer. Please install an EFI-compatible system. For example, Linux-Secure-Remix-64bit and Ubuntu-64bit are EFI-compatible systems.

So it turns out that my  newly installed windows is 64-bit and with EFI while my installed ubuntu is not EFI compatible (so it must be 32-bit?).

After reading around, it seems that this is actually the kind of thing that boot-repair should solve by default, yet I get that message. I couldn't really find any posts with the same problem so I'm stuck.

I was thinking of reinstalling ubuntu with a 64-bit version as suggested by the message but I would have to back up data from my home folder first which seems to be not doable at the moment (I stupidly encrypted that partition some time ago and do not a key...).

This is the log generated by boot-repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6692233/

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You guessed correctly :) According to line 673 of the Boot-Repair log, you have installed a 32bit version of Ubuntu.

You can reinstall Ubuntu-64bit above the current 32bit one while reusing your old /home. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation